# Why is element's parentNode undefined when accesses from inside document.ready() and window.load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, document-ready

I have a `<select>` element on my page which has `onchange` propery set:

```
<select id="MySelect" onchange="return myOnChange(this);">Whatever</select>
```

The event handler goes like this:

```
function myOnChange(select) {
   var parentNode = select.parentNode;
   //whatever
}
```

Once the page has loaded the user changes the selection inside the dropdown and the event handler is invoked and `parentNode` is bound to something (whatever it is, it's not undefined and that's enough).

However if I add a `document.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var select = $('#MySelect');
  var parentNode = select.parentNode;
  //whatever
});
```

or `window.load()`:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  var select = $('#MySelect');
  var parentNode = select.parentNode;
  //whatever
});
```

then once either of them is invoked then `parentNode` is undefined.

Why is this? How do I have my handler invoked once the page has loaded such that `parentNode` is not undefined?

Comment: jQuery functions return a list of nodes, not a DOM node.

Comment: @Oriol I'd say that this question is only a duplicate of that one for people who already know there're two kinds of objects. I had no idea of that - to me it was "working here but not there" and the answer was "there're two kinds of objects, here's how you access the right one".

Answer (score 2):

because here is no parentNode in a jQuery object.

```
var parentNode = select.parent()
```

or

```
var parentNode = select[0].parentNode;
```

Comment: Will I get a "regular" object if I use `select.get()`?

Comment: should note that first `parentNode` is also jQuery object

Comment: You will get the DOM element. yes

Comment: Yeap, using `.get(0)` gave me access to the node which I passed somewhere and that somewhere happily invoked `parentNode`. Could you please add usage of `get()` into the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing a node object's property over a jquery object,

```
var select = $('#MySelect');
var parentNode = select.parent();
```

You have to use jquery's `.parent()` function.

In your `onchange` event handler you are receiving the `this` as its parameter. Basically the `this` over their would represent the element which invokes the event. And that would be the `node` object. So over that you could access the property `parentNode`. But not over a jquery object.